# dd - No space left on device with microSD cards

Tags: dd

I'm working on Raspberry Pi OS on a Pi3B. I'm working with a script that does a few things for partitioning and there are times I want to wipe the drive, so I use (as root):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmblk0 status=progress bs=1M
```

And I always get this - even with different microSD cards and different sizes:

```
300941312 bytes (301 MB, 287 MiB) copied, 1 s, 301 MB/s
dd: error writing '/dev/mmblk0': No space left on device
340+0 records in
339+0 records out
356405248 bytes (356 MB, 340 MiB) copied, 1.20626 s, 295 MB/s
```

What is going on that this device runs out of space so quickly, without even 1GB used on 32, 64, or 128GB card? I can do this same thing on USB memory sticks without an issue, but I get this every time I do it on a microSD card.

Comment: I take it you've booted from something other than SD when you run this

Comment: also, check the output of `dmesg` just after you get this error

Comment: typo? `mmblk0` » `mmcblk0`? check `df -h /dev`, you might be filling your /dev tmpfs

Comment: @frostschutz Yes. See the answer (from @roaima) and my comment. It is really tough for me to see a typo like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On my Pi the SD cards are named `/dev/mmcblkN` (for values of `N` from 0). You typed `/dev/mmblk0`, which suggests you are filling the root filesystem instead of writing to the primary storage device.

You can verify this by looking at the file type (consider the first character of each line; `-` is a file, `b` is a block device):

```
ls -l /dev/mmblk0 /dev/mmcblk?
```

On my system,

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 179, 0 Jul  6 11:54 /dev/mmcblk0
```

Comment: Thank you! Due to a reading/learning disability, it can take me hours to find issues like that! When I was using Perl, back before 2005, if I used a colon instead of a semi-colon at the end of a line, and the compiler didn't give me a good line number for the error, it could take me hours to find that error. (If, in that case, I knew I was looking for a colon, it'd be easier and I could search the text for colons.) It's VERY difficult for me to see typos on my own!

Comment: These kind of errors can be very hard to spot - although it might be harder for you, @Tango, it's tricky for many people too

Comment: Thanks! I often have to retype a line, without looking at the line in issue, then copy and paste into a text editor to compare them. But with this - I was sure I had used tab completion for the device, and then I realized (after reading your post), that I couldn't, since that argument started with "of=", so I wasn't checking for typos.

Comment: @Tango: `dd of=` will tab complete if you have an appropriate shell and completions file installed (e.g. the default installs of bash or zsh on Ubuntu do it just fine).  However, if you make the typo once, then future attempts *will* tab complete because `/dev/mmblk0` now exists.

Comment: @NateEldredge: My desktop systems are Apple. (Part of the reasoning for that is because the terminal uses bash, zsh, and so on, so a lot of the time I'm on it, I'm in a familiar *nix-like environment.) Since Apple is moving from bash to zsh, and realizing bash hasn't been updated in a while, I'm moving over to zsh and still am learning all the little things to make zsh as customized as I want. Thanks for the info, since I can now look into how I can do that.